# How to custom CloudWatch Metrics with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mandrill, amazon-cloudwatch

I want know is any simple way can modify aws lambda (python) metrics?

I write a lambda to receive mandrill webhook, I want use CloudWatch to compare lambda exec time and webhook items (mandrill will send multi log in a webhook request).

The way I currently found not best practice I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Python SDK to write the CloudWatch metric:

https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/cloudwatch.html#CloudWatch.Client.put_metric_data